# Users database to store access levels, can I move the non-essential information to another table?

Tags: erd, database-design

I would like some advice on the best database structure for my system.

I have different kinds of users with different access levels, and different information of course. I created a `users` table with the following fields:

```
id
student_number
password
first_name
last_name
address
email
mothers_name
mothers_occupation
fathers_name
fathers_occupation
religion
civil_status
```

The problem is that some users just don't need all those fields. The only user type that needs all those are the `students` users. The student users have a different 'environment' / module that sends a request to an api, that then sends back a json response.

Other fields, for other type of users, are not applicable to them, for example, an admin, he/she mustn't have those other fields (I could use dummy data, but I am looking for a cleaner approach).

I was thinking I can just create tables like this:

**Users table**

```
id
username
password
```

**UserInfo table:**

```
user_id (FK)
first_name
last_name
...
```

What do you think? Any examples/erd of big `users` database?

Comment: Just keep them as one table and use `NULL` appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

```
Users.

id, student_number, password, first_name, last_name, address, email, mothers_name,  
mothers_occupation, fathers_name, fathers_occupation, religion, civil_status

Roles
id, name

UserRoleMembership
user_id, role_id
```

If the problem is that you actually do want to validate some of those fields - but only for some users, I would use inheritance:

```
users
id, username, password

student_user
id,
user_id,
last_name required,
first_name required,
etc.

admin_user
id,
user_id,
admin_info_fields...
```

Comment: Just personal preference, but I'd stick with one table with a "user_type" column.